# Isometric hexagonal tilemap

Tags: flutter, isometric, flame

I want to create an isometric tilemap with hexagons instead of squares, like in the image:

[image: Isometric hexagonal tilemap example]

How would one achieve this? I'm having problem with positioning the tiles correctly, as well as detecting which tile is clicked.

Simply using `IsometricTileMapComponent` with hexagon tiles causes the tiles to overlap incorrectly.

One possible solution is to `extend` the `IsometricTileMapComponent` and override the appropriate methods, primarily (I think) the following two:

```dart
/// Get which block's surface is at isometric position [p].
///
/// This can be used to handle clicks or hovers.
/// This is the opposite of [getBlockCenterPosition].
Block getBlock(Vector2 p) {
  // How to implement this?
}

/// Get the position in which a block is rendered in, in the isometric space.
///
/// This does not include the (x,y) PositionComponent offset!
/// This assumes the tile sprite as a rectangular tile.
/// This is the opposite of [getBlockRenderedAt].
Vector2 getBlockRenderPositionInts(int i, int j) {
  // My implementation, I think this works as intended...
  return Vector2((i - j) * surfaceSize.x * 0.75, (i + j) * surfaceSize.y / 2);
}
```

But I don't know how the first method would look for a hexagonal isometric space. Perhaps [this](http://playtechs.blogspot.com/2007/04/hex-grids.html) article could be helpful, but I'm having problems figuring out the proper maths.

Comment: Have you tried flame_tiled? If I remember correctly there is some support for hexagonal tiles in there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! There seems to be support for hexagonal tiles but not for hexagonal isometric tiles, as far as I could tell? Either way I need something that can be easily generated through code (more like what `IsometricTileMapComponent` does) which as I understand it is not the purpose of flame_tiled.

Comment: Alright, I'm afraid that doesn't exist yet then.
If you build it, feel free to put up a PR with that component to Flame. :)

Comment: I will try, but having problem figuring out the maths...not my expertise so to say :). If I do get it working, I'll post a PR!